# Incorporating Tweets into MySQL loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I need to output a tweet every two results outputted from a mysql query. The page in question is [here](https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/testMasonryDev.php) to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

Here is the code I am using so far, which isn't working...

```
 foreach($multi_array as $key => $value ){

// start tweet output for loop. twitter authentication is before this foreach loop

 ?>
<div id="masonry-container">
<?php 

$dbleads = new mysqli('localhost','****','*****','******'); 

$query = mysqli_query($dbleads, "SELECT * FROM plugin_blog ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $row['html'], $matches);
    $img = $matches[1];
    ++$i;
    ++$j;
    if ($i%2 == 0){
            if($j%10==0){
             echo "<div class='masonryImage tweets' style='width:300px; height:175px;'><div class='tweet-content'>" . $value['text'] . "</div></div>";
            }
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:250px;'>" . $img . " </div>";
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

UPDATE: Now managed to put the tweets in the right place, however, only one tweet is being displayed, and it is echoing the first five letters of that tweet, here is the code I have used:

```
foreach($multi_array as $key => $value ){
// printing each tweet wrapped in a <li> tag
$tweets = $value['text'];
}

$dbleads = new mysqli('********','***********','**********','************'); 

$query = mysqli_query($dbleads, "SELECT * FROM plugin_blog WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$i = 0;
$j=-1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $row['html'], $matches);
    $img = $matches[1];
    ++$i;
    if ($i%2 == 0){
        ++$j;
        echo "<div class='masonryImage tweets' style='width:300px; height:175px;'><div class='tweet-content'>" . $tweets[$j] . "</div></div>";
        echo $j; // here only for debugging, checking the counter works
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:200px;'>" . $img . " </div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
$tweets = $value['text'];
```

To

```
$tweets[] = $value['text'];
```

To create the array $tweets; otherwise when using $tweets[$i] you're only getting that single letter at index $i

Comment: Thanks a lot, you bring home the bacon! Top job :) will give the bounty when Stack Overflow lets me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a result at following:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
var_dump($row);
```

Then you are failing at

```
if ($i%2 == 0) {

            if($j%10==0){
```

Your query limit is 10 you go into every 2 then every 10 I guess you never go into second if.
Check to see if you go into first `if ($i%2 ==0) {echo 'i am in';}`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tip, I echoed what you suggested, and it stays inside the first if statement fine. What's the next step?

Comment: Check to see if you go into second if...you probably will never go to second if...Just remove that if you do not need it.

Comment: Actually, it echoes both the first and second if, does that help?

Comment: I guess your $value['text'] is empty. Check your browsers source code by right click view source. You will probably see your <div>'s there. I guess you $value['text'] is empty. Write something else in your dynamic fields.

Comment: $value['text'] is outputting fine, those are the tweets

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, instead of your current 1 tweet to every 9 images, you want 1 tweet to every 1 image? I cannot understand why you have both `$i` and `$j` in your loop, so as `$i` already gives you the "every other" concept, I simply deleted all mention of `$j` :-)

```
foreach($multi_array as $key => $value ){

// start tweet output for loop. twitter authentication is before this foreach loop

 ?>
<div id="masonry-container">
<?php 

$dbleads = new mysqli('localhost','****','*****','******'); 

$query = mysqli_query($dbleads, "SELECT * FROM plugin_blog ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$i = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $row['html'], $matches);
    $img = $matches[1];
    ++$i;
    if ($i%2 == 0){
        echo "<div class='masonryImage tweets' style='width:300px; height:175px;'><div class='tweet-content'>" . $value['text'] . "</div></div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:250px;'>" . $img . " </div>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's now outputting every two images, which is great news! :) However, it is outputting 5 of each tweet. Any ideas? Nearly there! (The twitter script is retrieving 5 tweets, so not sure if that is linked to the problem? Shouldn't think so)

Comment: Edited my question to show you what else I have tried now! Thanks :)